# Moments of subgaussian quadratic form

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ have independent, mean zero entries that are strictly subgaussian with parameter $\sigma^{2}$ and let $A=ab^{\top}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$. I am interested in computing
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[(X^{\top}AX)^{q}],
\end{equation}
for $q\in\mathbb{N}$. For example, when $q=1$, it is easy to see that this is just $\sigma^{2}\text{Tr}(A)=\sigma^{2}(a^{\top}b)$.

This work [1] for example computes the first four moments when $X$ is Gaussian and $A$ is symmetric [equation 2.32]. Overall, it is a combination of polynomials in the trace of $A$ (or its higher powers).

Any ideas on how this would extend to subgaussian $X$ and nonsymmetric rank-one $A=ab^{\top}$?

---

[1] Issie Scarowsky, Quadratic forms in normal variables. 1973

Comment: we can't access the link you provided. I don't know much about subgaussian variables but intuitively it seems difficult to obtain a general formula when moments higher than 2 are involved as subgaussian distributions seem to be loosely defined and encompass as a result a large variety of possible distribution (but my intuition might be wrong)

Comment: Note also that in the case of a subgaussian variable with parameter sigma^2, the variance is not sigma^2 : see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131066/572435

Comment: @Jeanba Added the reference. I'm hoping a general formula can be obtained because we can bound the moments of $X$ (so maybe an upper bound can be obtained for the moment in question)

Comment: For strictly subgaussian rvs, they are the same (which is why I specified in the question)